# How to send an outbound message to endpoint URL when an attachment is created on case object?

Tags: visualforce, trigger, community, workflow

I want to send an outbound message to external url when a new attachment is created on case object, please help me this.

Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 1):

You can't currently create a workflow rule for Attachments, so you can't use it to send the attachment via an outbound message.

Instead, consider creating a trigger on attachments, that checks to see if the record is for a Case.

Being a trigger, you can't immediately make callouts to the external URL. Instead you will probably need to use a future methods that is marked to make callouts.